# How to get images in the product list view with an API call in Shopware?

Tags: rest, api, thumbnails, shopware

I’m working on a single-page-application with fully client-side rendered frontend (React) and Shopware acting as a headless CMS in the background. So all product-data will be pulled from the API and checkout will also use the API to send the data.

**My problem is the following:**

When trying to render the product list page, I call the [articles endpoint](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/examples/article/#example-2-get-(list)) which returns the basic info of all my products. The problem is that I would also need to render the main image associated with each product and this list does not expose any data from the media attached to the products.

I can get the media item(s) for a product using the [Media endpoint](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-media/), problem is that this one expects a Media Id which I cannot get from the listed representations of the articles.

So right now the only way I see to get the images is first making a call that gets all the products, then loop through them and get each product’s details, calling the article endpoint again with each product ID, then when I have the media IDs I loop through those and get the images for each product using the media endpoint, because that’s the only one that exposes the actual image path in the response. This seems way too complicated and slow.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Can I get Shopware to output the 1st image’s path in the Article list response, that’s associated with the current product?

Also I saw that the paths to the images look like this:
*/media/image/f5/fb/95/03_200x200.jpg*

The first part up to **/media/image/** is fixed, that’s straight forward, and I get the image’s filename and extension in the article detail’s response in the media object and even the file extension, [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA0JV.png) in the API's response.

The problem is that I don’t know what’s the **f5/fb/95/** stand for. If I could get this info from the details I could assemble the URL for the image programmatically and then I wouldn’t need the call to the media endpoint.

Comment: your first link contains images such as http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food/ can you use those?

Comment: @codebrane - I don't see any images like that on my first link (if by "first link" you're meaning this one: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/examples/article/#example-2-get-(list)).
Also these are placeholders, I need to get the actual images uploaded to Shopware.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how the path is generated in the class [\Shopware\Bundle\MediaBundle\Strategy\Md5Strategy](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/e3f1b89af0abe32ae26c945bf57b3e0535fcab6d/engine/Shopware/Bundle/MediaBundle/Strategy/Md5Strategy.php) of Shopware's source code. The two relevant methods are:

```
<?php

public function normalize($path)
{
    // remove filesystem directories
    $path = str_replace('//', '/', $path);

    // remove everything before /media/...
    preg_match("/.*((media\/(?:archive|image|music|pdf|temp|unknown|video|vector)(?:\/thumbnail)?).*\/((.+)\.(.+)))/", $path, $matches);

    if (!empty($matches)) {
        return $matches[2] . '/' . $matches[3];
    }

    return $path;
}

public function encode($path)
{
    if (!$path || $this->isEncoded($path)) {
        return $this->substringPath($path);
    }

    $path = $this->normalize($path);

    $path = ltrim($path, '/');
    $pathElements = explode('/', $path);
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($path);
    $md5hash = md5($path);

    if (empty($pathInfo['extension'])) {
        return '';
    }

    $realPath = array_slice(str_split($md5hash, 2), 0, 3);
    $realPath = $pathElements[0] . '/' . $pathElements[1] . '/' . join('/', $realPath) . '/' . $pathInfo['basename'];

    if (!$this->hasBlacklistParts($realPath)) {
        return $realPath;
    }

    foreach ($this->blacklist as $key => $value) {
        $realPath = str_replace($key, $value, $realPath);
    }

    return $realPath;
}
```

Step for step, this happens generally to an image path, for example `https://example.com/media/image/my_image.jpg`, upon passing it to the `encode`-method:

1. The `normalize` method strips everything except for `media/image/my_image.jpg`
2. An md5-hash is generated out of the resulting string: `5dc18cdfa0...`
3. The resulting string from step 1 is split at every `/`: `['media', 'image', 'my_image.jpg']`
4. The first three character pairs from the md5-hash are being stored into an array: `['5d', 'c1', '8c']`
5. The final path is being assembled out of the arrays from steps 3 and 4: `media/image/5d/c1/8c/my_image.jpg`
6. Every occurence of `/ad/` is being replaced by `/g0/`. This is done, because [there are ad-blockers which block requests to URLs containing `/ad/`](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/SW-12910)

Answer (score 0):

Shopware computes the path for you.

There is acutally no need to know about the hashed path...

You will be redirected to the correct path.

Try the following:

```
/media/image/ + image['path'] + image['extension']
```

An for the thumbnails:

```
/media/image/thumbnail/ + image['path'] + '_200x200' + image['extension']
or
/media/image/thumbnail/ + image['path'] + '_600x600' + image['extension']
```